Is this latch on/latch off circuit involving USB-C correct?
I'm having a lot of trouble getting a clear understanding of transistors/MOSFETs.
I'm currently trying to nail down the USB and power side of my overall circuit. I am completely self-taught with electronics, and there are obvious gaps in my knowledge. I was just wondering before I order another board, whether this circuit looks right and will work?
Anyhow, the function of this part of the circuit should be:

Single button toggles all the power on & off.
LED-D8 in-line with the VBUS/VCC goes on when the USB is connected.
The diode set-up isolates the resistor and LED-D8 from affecting main VCC.
When the power is latched on, LED-D3 in-line with VCC lights up, showing that the whole circuit is turned on.

FINAL UPDATE


Q1 has pins 2 and 3 both connected to Vcc ... same with D2 ... SW4 does not do anything

@happycamper1221 With the update schematic SW4 still does not do anything.

@happycamper1221 you corrected the Vcc problem ... SW4 still does nothing electrically

No. Look carefully at SW4. When SW4 is closed, pin 1 connects to pin 2, and pin 3 connects to pin 4. But there is nothing connected to either pin 1 or pin 4. So the switch does nothing at all. Also, this circuit has nothing to do with USB-C. You are just making a power switching circuit. But you will be getting no power from USB-C with the circuit as shown. With USB-C, VBUS is off until the power source detects and confirms the load. You have none of the resistors of chips used to do that, so nothing will happen. When testing, do not use USB-A to USB-C cables as they give misleading results.

When you'll use a USB-C power supply (commonly but incorrectly called "USB-C Charger"), then the circuit above will have 0V on VBUS and will remain that way forever.

You show nothing on CC pins. With nothing connected there, VBUS will be 0V unless you're using a passive Type-A to Type-C cable. So, to make sure you're doing it right, use a Type-C to Type-C cable with a "USB-C Charger". With CC1 and CC2 open, you will get nothing on VBUS.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I believe I have it right now. Will this now work as intended?

There is still no apparent effect of pushing SW4.
